# Installable plugins for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to create a Rails application. A kind of "core" app, where a user can install additional plugins. Those plugins should integrate into the app, and the user shouldn't have to change the app code to have it works.

Any hints where I should look for creating plugins like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's a very generic question. You might want to take a look into [Radiant CMS](http://radiantcms.org/). It's a Rails based CMS with the concept of "extensions".